# Java change of value, reason?

Tags: java, encryption, aes

Actually, I was writing an algorithm for AES encrytion/decryption. And, following is my code which not working properly:

```
public class AESAlgorithm {

//standard table for AES algorithm do not change it is fixed
private static final int[] sbox = new int[]{
    0x63, 0x7c, 0x77, 0x7b, 0xf2, 0x6b, 0x6f, 0xc5, 0x30, 0x01, 0x67, 0x2b, 0xfe, 0xd7, 0xab, 0x76,
    0xca, 0x82, 0xc9, 0x7d, 0xfa, 0x59, 0x47, 0xf0, 0xad, 0xd4, 0xa2, 0xaf, 0x9c, 0xa4, 0x72, 0xc0,
    0xb7, 0xfd, 0x93, 0x26, 0x36, 0x3f, 0xf7, 0xcc, 0x34, 0xa5, 0xe5, 0xf1, 0x71, 0xd8, 0x31, 0x15,
    0x04, 0xc7, 0x23, 0xc3, 0x18, 0x96, 0x05, 0x9a, 0x07, 0x12, 0x80, 0xe2, 0xeb, 0x27, 0xb2, 0x75,
    0x09, 0x83, 0x2c, 0x1a, 0x1b, 0x6e, 0x5a, 0xa0, 0x52, 0x3b, 0xd6, 0xb3, 0x29, 0xe3, 0x2f, 0x84,
    0x53, 0xd1, 0x00, 0xed, 0x20, 0xfc, 0xb1, 0x5b, 0x6a, 0xcb, 0xbe, 0x39, 0x4a, 0x4c, 0x58, 0xcf,
    0xd0, 0xef, 0xaa, 0xfb, 0x43, 0x4d, 0x33, 0x85, 0x45, 0xf9, 0x02, 0x7f, 0x50, 0x3c, 0x9f, 0xa8,
    0x51, 0xa3, 0x40, 0x8f, 0x92, 0x9d, 0x38, 0xf5, 0xbc, 0xb6, 0xda, 0x21, 0x10, 0xff, 0xf3, 0xd2,
    0xcd, 0x0c, 0x13, 0xec, 0x5f, 0x97, 0x44, 0x17, 0xc4, 0xa7, 0x7e, 0x3d, 0x64, 0x5d, 0x19, 0x73,
    0x60, 0x81, 0x4f, 0xdc, 0x22, 0x2a, 0x90, 0x88, 0x46, 0xee, 0xb8, 0x14, 0xde, 0x5e, 0x0b, 0xdb,
    0xe0, 0x32, 0x3a, 0x0a, 0x49, 0x06, 0x24, 0x5c, 0xc2, 0xd3, 0xac, 0x62, 0x91, 0x95, 0xe4, 0x79,
    0xe7, 0xc8, 0x37, 0x6d, 0x8d, 0xd5, 0x4e, 0xa9, 0x6c, 0x56, 0xf4, 0xea, 0x65, 0x7a, 0xae, 0x08,
    0xba, 0x78, 0x25, 0x2e, 0x1c, 0xa6, 0xb4, 0xc6, 0xe8, 0xdd, 0x74, 0x1f, 0x4b, 0xbd, 0x8b, 0x8a,
    0x70, 0x3e, 0xb5, 0x66, 0x48, 0x03, 0xf6, 0x0e, 0x61, 0x35, 0x57, 0xb9, 0x86, 0xc1, 0x1d, 0x9e,
    0xe1, 0xf8, 0x98, 0x11, 0x69, 0xd9, 0x8e, 0x94, 0x9b, 0x1e, 0x87, 0xe9, 0xce, 0x55, 0x28, 0xdf,
    0x8c, 0xa1, 0x89, 0x0d, 0xbf, 0xe6, 0x42, 0x68, 0x41, 0x99, 0x2d, 0x0f, 0xb0, 0x54, 0xbb, 0x16
};

private static final int[] invSBOx = {
    0x52, 0x09, 0x6a, 0xd5, 0x30, 0x36, 0xa5, 0x38, 0xbf, 0x40, 0xa3, 0x9e, 0x81, 0xf3, 0xd7, 0xfb,
    0x7c, 0xe3, 0x39, 0x82, 0x9b, 0x2f, 0xff, 0x87, 0x34, 0x8e, 0x43, 0x44, 0xc4, 0xde, 0xe9, 0xcb,
    0x54, 0x7b, 0x94, 0x32, 0xa6, 0xc2, 0x23, 0x3d, 0xee, 0x4c, 0x95, 0x0b, 0x42, 0xfa, 0xc3, 0x4e,
    0x08, 0x2e, 0xa1, 0x66, 0x28, 0xd9, 0x24, 0xb2, 0x76, 0x5b, 0xa2, 0x49, 0x6d, 0x8b, 0xd1, 0x25,
    0x72, 0xf8, 0xf6, 0x64, 0x86, 0x68, 0x98, 0x16, 0xd4, 0xa4, 0x5c, 0xcc, 0x5d, 0x65, 0xb6, 0x92,
    0x6c, 0x70, 0x48, 0x50, 0xfd, 0xed, 0xb9, 0xda, 0x5e, 0x15, 0x46, 0x57, 0xa7, 0x8d, 0x9d, 0x84,
    0x90, 0xd8, 0xab, 0x00, 0x8c, 0xbc, 0xd3, 0x0a, 0xf7, 0xe4, 0x58, 0x05, 0xb8, 0xb3, 0x45, 0x06,
    0xd0, 0x2c, 0x1e, 0x8f, 0xca, 0x3f, 0x0f, 0x02, 0xc1, 0xaf, 0xbd, 0x03, 0x01, 0x13, 0x8a, 0x6b,
    0x3a, 0x91, 0x11, 0x41, 0x4f, 0x67, 0xdc, 0xea, 0x97, 0xf2, 0xcf, 0xce, 0xf0, 0xb4, 0xe6, 0x73,
    0x96, 0xac, 0x74, 0x22, 0xe7, 0xad, 0x35, 0x85, 0xe2, 0xf9, 0x37, 0xe8, 0x1c, 0x75, 0xdf, 0x6e,
    0x47, 0xf1, 0x1a, 0x71, 0x1d, 0x29, 0xc5, 0x89, 0x6f, 0xb7, 0x62, 0x0e, 0xaa, 0x18, 0xbe, 0x1b,
    0xfc, 0x56, 0x3e, 0x4b, 0xc6, 0xd2, 0x79, 0x20, 0x9a, 0xdb, 0xc0, 0xfe, 0x78, 0xcd, 0x5a, 0xf4,
    0x1f, 0xdd, 0xa8, 0x33, 0x88, 0x07, 0xc7, 0x31, 0xb1, 0x12, 0x10, 0x59, 0x27, 0x80, 0xec, 0x5f,
    0x60, 0x51, 0x7f, 0xa9, 0x19, 0xb5, 0x4a, 0x0d, 0x2d, 0xe5, 0x7a, 0x9f, 0x93, 0xc9, 0x9c, 0xef,
    0xa0, 0xe0, 0x3b, 0x4d, 0xae, 0x2a, 0xf5, 0xb0, 0xc8, 0xeb, 0xbb, 0x3c, 0x83, 0x53, 0x99, 0x61,
    0x17, 0x2b, 0x04, 0x7e, 0xba, 0x77, 0xd6, 0x26, 0xe1, 0x69, 0x14, 0x63, 0x55, 0x21, 0x0c, 0x7d
};

private final int[] mul2 = new int[]{
    0x00, 0x02, 0x04, 0x06, 0x08, 0x0a, 0x0c, 0x0e, 0x10, 0x12, 0x14, 0x16, 0x18, 0x1a, 0x1c, 0x1e,
    0x20, 0x22, 0x24, 0x26, 0x28, 0x2a, 0x2c, 0x2e, 0x30, 0x32, 0x34, 0x36, 0x38, 0x3a, 0x3c, 0x3e,
    0x40, 0x42, 0x44, 0x46, 0x48, 0x4a, 0x4c, 0x4e, 0x50, 0x52, 0x54, 0x56, 0x58, 0x5a, 0x5c, 0x5e,
    0x60, 0x62, 0x64, 0x66, 0x68, 0x6a, 0x6c, 0x6e, 0x70, 0x72, 0x74, 0x76, 0x78, 0x7a, 0x7c, 0x7e,
    0x80, 0x82, 0x84, 0x86, 0x88, 0x8a, 0x8c, 0x8e, 0x90, 0x92, 0x94, 0x96, 0x98, 0x9a, 0x9c, 0x9e,
    0xa0, 0xa2, 0xa4, 0xa6, 0xa8, 0xaa, 0xac, 0xae, 0xb0, 0xb2, 0xb4, 0xb6, 0xb8, 0xba, 0xbc, 0xbe,
    0xc0, 0xc2, 0xc4, 0xc6, 0xc8, 0xca, 0xcc, 0xce, 0xd0, 0xd2, 0xd4, 0xd6, 0xd8, 0xda, 0xdc, 0xde,
    0xe0, 0xe2, 0xe4, 0xe6, 0xe8, 0xea, 0xec, 0xee, 0xf0, 0xf2, 0xf4, 0xf6, 0xf8, 0xfa, 0xfc, 0xfe,
    0x1b, 0x19, 0x1f, 0x1d, 0x13, 0x11, 0x17, 0x15, 0x0b, 0x09, 0x0f, 0x0d, 0x03, 0x01, 0x07, 0x05,
    0x3b, 0x39, 0x3f, 0x3d, 0x33, 0x31, 0x37, 0x35, 0x2b, 0x29, 0x2f, 0x2d, 0x23, 0x21, 0x27, 0x25,
    0x5b, 0x59, 0x5f, 0x5d, 0x53, 0x51, 0x57, 0x55, 0x4b, 0x49, 0x4f, 0x4d, 0x43, 0x41, 0x47, 0x45,
    0x7b, 0x79, 0x7f, 0x7d, 0x73, 0x71, 0x77, 0x75, 0x6b, 0x69, 0x6f, 0x6d, 0x63, 0x61, 0x67, 0x65,
    0x9b, 0x99, 0x9f, 0x9d, 0x93, 0x91, 0x97, 0x95, 0x8b, 0x89, 0x8f, 0x8d, 0x83, 0x81, 0x87, 0x85,
    0xbb, 0xb9, 0xbf, 0xbd, 0xb3, 0xb1, 0xb7, 0xb5, 0xab, 0xa9, 0xaf, 0xad, 0xa3, 0xa1, 0xa7, 0xa5,
    0xdb, 0xd9, 0xdf, 0xdd, 0xd3, 0xd1, 0xd7, 0xd5, 0xcb, 0xc9, 0xcf, 0xcd, 0xc3, 0xc1, 0xc7, 0xc5,
    0xfb, 0xf9, 0xff, 0xfd, 0xf3, 0xf1, 0xf7, 0xf5, 0xeb, 0xe9, 0xef, 0xed, 0xe3, 0xe1, 0xe7, 0xe5
};

private final int[] mul3 = new int[]{
    0x00, 0x03, 0x06, 0x05, 0x0c, 0x0f, 0x0a, 0x09, 0x18, 0x1b, 0x1e, 0x1d, 0x14, 0x17, 0x12, 0x11,
    0x30, 0x33, 0x36, 0x35, 0x3c, 0x3f, 0x3a, 0x39, 0x28, 0x2b, 0x2e, 0x2d, 0x24, 0x27, 0x22, 0x21,
    0x60, 0x63, 0x66, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6f, 0x6a, 0x69, 0x78, 0x7b, 0x7e, 0x7d, 0x74, 0x77, 0x72, 0x71,
    0x50, 0x53, 0x56, 0x55, 0x5c, 0x5f, 0x5a, 0x59, 0x48, 0x4b, 0x4e, 0x4d, 0x44, 0x47, 0x42, 0x41,
    0xc0, 0xc3, 0xc6, 0xc5, 0xcc, 0xcf, 0xca, 0xc9, 0xd8, 0xdb, 0xde, 0xdd, 0xd4, 0xd7, 0xd2, 0xd1,
    0xf0, 0xf3, 0xf6, 0xf5, 0xfc, 0xff, 0xfa, 0xf9, 0xe8, 0xeb, 0xee, 0xed, 0xe4, 0xe7, 0xe2, 0xe1,
    0xa0, 0xa3, 0xa6, 0xa5, 0xac, 0xaf, 0xaa, 0xa9, 0xb8, 0xbb, 0xbe, 0xbd, 0xb4, 0xb7, 0xb2, 0xb1,
    0x90, 0x93, 0x96, 0x95, 0x9c, 0x9f, 0x9a, 0x99, 0x88, 0x8b, 0x8e, 0x8d, 0x84, 0x87, 0x82, 0x81,
    0x9b, 0x98, 0x9d, 0x9e, 0x97, 0x94, 0x91, 0x92, 0x83, 0x80, 0x85, 0x86, 0x8f, 0x8c, 0x89, 0x8a,
    0xab, 0xa8, 0xad, 0xae, 0xa7, 0xa4, 0xa1, 0xa2, 0xb3, 0xb0, 0xb5, 0xb6, 0xbf, 0xbc, 0xb9, 0xba,
    0xfb, 0xf8, 0xfd, 0xfe, 0xf7, 0xf4, 0xf1, 0xf2, 0xe3, 0xe0, 0xe5, 0xe6, 0xef, 0xec, 0xe9, 0xea,
    0xcb, 0xc8, 0xcd, 0xce, 0xc7, 0xc4, 0xc1, 0xc2, 0xd3, 0xd0, 0xd5, 0xd6, 0xdf, 0xdc, 0xd9, 0xda,
    0x5b, 0x58, 0x5d, 0x5e, 0x57, 0x54, 0x51, 0x52, 0x43, 0x40, 0x45, 0x46, 0x4f, 0x4c, 0x49, 0x4a,
    0x6b, 0x68, 0x6d, 0x6e, 0x67, 0x64, 0x61, 0x62, 0x73, 0x70, 0x75, 0x76, 0x7f, 0x7c, 0x79, 0x7a,
    0x3b, 0x38, 0x3d, 0x3e, 0x37, 0x34, 0x31, 0x32, 0x23, 0x20, 0x25, 0x26, 0x2f, 0x2c, 0x29, 0x2a,
    0x0b, 0x08, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x07, 0x04, 0x01, 0x02, 0x13, 0x10, 0x15, 0x16, 0x1f, 0x1c, 0x19, 0x1a
};

private static final int[] rcon = new int[]{
    0x8d, 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80, 0x1b, 0x36, 0x6c, 0xd8, 0xab, 0x4d, 0x9a,
    0x2f, 0x5e, 0xbc, 0x63, 0xc6, 0x97, 0x35, 0x6a, 0xd4, 0xb3, 0x7d, 0xfa, 0xef, 0xc5, 0x91, 0x39,
    0x72, 0xe4, 0xd3, 0xbd, 0x61, 0xc2, 0x9f, 0x25, 0x4a, 0x94, 0x33, 0x66, 0xcc, 0x83, 0x1d, 0x3a,
    0x74, 0xe8, 0xcb, 0x8d, 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80, 0x1b, 0x36, 0x6c, 0xd8,
    0xab, 0x4d, 0x9a, 0x2f, 0x5e, 0xbc, 0x63, 0xc6, 0x97, 0x35, 0x6a, 0xd4, 0xb3, 0x7d, 0xfa, 0xef,
    0xc5, 0x91, 0x39, 0x72, 0xe4, 0xd3, 0xbd, 0x61, 0xc2, 0x9f, 0x25, 0x4a, 0x94, 0x33, 0x66, 0xcc,
    0x83, 0x1d, 0x3a, 0x74, 0xe8, 0xcb, 0x8d, 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80, 0x1b,
    0x36, 0x6c, 0xd8, 0xab, 0x4d, 0x9a, 0x2f, 0x5e, 0xbc, 0x63, 0xc6, 0x97, 0x35, 0x6a, 0xd4, 0xb3,
    0x7d, 0xfa, 0xef, 0xc5, 0x91, 0x39, 0x72, 0xe4, 0xd3, 0xbd, 0x61, 0xc2, 0x9f, 0x25, 0x4a, 0x94,
    0x33, 0x66, 0xcc, 0x83, 0x1d, 0x3a, 0x74, 0xe8, 0xcb, 0x8d, 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10, 0x20,
    0x40, 0x80, 0x1b, 0x36, 0x6c, 0xd8, 0xab, 0x4d, 0x9a, 0x2f, 0x5e, 0xbc, 0x63, 0xc6, 0x97, 0x35,
    0x6a, 0xd4, 0xb3, 0x7d, 0xfa, 0xef, 0xc5, 0x91, 0x39, 0x72, 0xe4, 0xd3, 0xbd, 0x61, 0xc2, 0x9f,
    0x25, 0x4a, 0x94, 0x33, 0x66, 0xcc, 0x83, 0x1d, 0x3a, 0x74, 0xe8, 0xcb, 0x8d, 0x01, 0x02, 0x04,
    0x08, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80, 0x1b, 0x36, 0x6c, 0xd8, 0xab, 0x4d, 0x9a, 0x2f, 0x5e, 0xbc, 0x63,
    0xc6, 0x97, 0x35, 0x6a, 0xd4, 0xb3, 0x7d, 0xfa, 0xef, 0xc5, 0x91, 0x39, 0x72, 0xe4, 0xd3, 0xbd,
    0x61, 0xc2, 0x9f, 0x25, 0x4a, 0x94, 0x33, 0x66, 0xcc, 0x83, 0x1d, 0x3a, 0x74, 0xe8, 0xcb, 0x8d
};

private final int[] mul9 = new int[]{
    0x00, 0x09, 0x12, 0x1b, 0x24, 0x2d, 0x36, 0x3f, 0x48, 0x41, 0x5a, 0x53, 0x6c, 0x65, 0x7e, 0x77,
    0x90, 0x99, 0x82, 0x8b, 0xb4, 0xbd, 0xa6, 0xaf, 0xd8, 0xd1, 0xca, 0xc3, 0xfc, 0xf5, 0xee, 0xe7,
    0x3b, 0x32, 0x29, 0x20, 0x1f, 0x16, 0x0d, 0x04, 0x73, 0x7a, 0x61, 0x68, 0x57, 0x5e, 0x45, 0x4c,
    0xab, 0xa2, 0xb9, 0xb0, 0x8f, 0x86, 0x9d, 0x94, 0xe3, 0xea, 0xf1, 0xf8, 0xc7, 0xce, 0xd5, 0xdc,
    0x76, 0x7f, 0x64, 0x6d, 0x52, 0x5b, 0x40, 0x49, 0x3e, 0x37, 0x2c, 0x25, 0x1a, 0x13, 0x08, 0x01,
    0xe6, 0xef, 0xf4, 0xfd, 0xc2, 0xcb, 0xd0, 0xd9, 0xae, 0xa7, 0xbc, 0xb5, 0x8a, 0x83, 0x98, 0x91,
    0x4d, 0x44, 0x5f, 0x56, 0x69, 0x60, 0x7b, 0x72, 0x05, 0x0c, 0x17, 0x1e, 0x21, 0x28, 0x33, 0x3a,
    0xdd, 0xd4, 0xcf, 0xc6, 0xf9, 0xf0, 0xeb, 0xe2, 0x95, 0x9c, 0x87, 0x8e, 0xb1, 0xb8, 0xa3, 0xaa,
    0xec, 0xe5, 0xfe, 0xf7, 0xc8, 0xc1, 0xda, 0xd3, 0xa4, 0xad, 0xb6, 0xbf, 0x80, 0x89, 0x92, 0x9b,
    0x7c, 0x75, 0x6e, 0x67, 0x58, 0x51, 0x4a, 0x43, 0x34, 0x3d, 0x26, 0x2f, 0x10, 0x19, 0x02, 0x0b,
    0xd7, 0xde, 0xc5, 0xcc, 0xf3, 0xfa, 0xe1, 0xe8, 0x9f, 0x96, 0x8d, 0x84, 0xbb, 0xb2, 0xa9, 0xa0,
    0x47, 0x4e, 0x55, 0x5c, 0x63, 0x6a, 0x71, 0x78, 0x0f, 0x06, 0x1d, 0x14, 0x2b, 0x22, 0x39, 0x30,
    0x9a, 0x93, 0x88, 0x81, 0xbe, 0xb7, 0xac, 0xa5, 0xd2, 0xdb, 0xc0, 0xc9, 0xf6, 0xff, 0xe4, 0xed,
    0x0a, 0x03, 0x18, 0x11, 0x2e, 0x27, 0x3c, 0x35, 0x42, 0x4b, 0x50, 0x59, 0x66, 0x6f, 0x74, 0x7d,
    0xa1, 0xa8, 0xb3, 0xba, 0x85, 0x8c, 0x97, 0x9e, 0xe9, 0xe0, 0xfb, 0xf2, 0xcd, 0xc4, 0xdf, 0xd6,
    0x31, 0x38, 0x23, 0x2a, 0x15, 0x1c, 0x07, 0x0e, 0x79, 0x70, 0x6b, 0x62, 0x5d, 0x54, 0x4f, 0x46
};

private final int[] mul11 = new int[]{
    0x00, 0x0b, 0x16, 0x1d, 0x2c, 0x27, 0x3a, 0x31, 0x58, 0x53, 0x4e, 0x45, 0x74, 0x7f, 0x62, 0x69,
    0xb0, 0xbb, 0xa6, 0xad, 0x9c, 0x97, 0x8a, 0x81, 0xe8, 0xe3, 0xfe, 0xf5, 0xc4, 0xcf, 0xd2, 0xd9,
    0x7b, 0x70, 0x6d, 0x66, 0x57, 0x5c, 0x41, 0x4a, 0x23, 0x28, 0x35, 0x3e, 0x0f, 0x04, 0x19, 0x12,
    0xcb, 0xc0, 0xdd, 0xd6, 0xe7, 0xec, 0xf1, 0xfa, 0x93, 0x98, 0x85, 0x8e, 0xbf, 0xb4, 0xa9, 0xa2,
    0xf6, 0xfd, 0xe0, 0xeb, 0xda, 0xd1, 0xcc, 0xc7, 0xae, 0xa5, 0xb8, 0xb3, 0x82, 0x89, 0x94, 0x9f,
    0x46, 0x4d, 0x50, 0x5b, 0x6a, 0x61, 0x7c, 0x77, 0x1e, 0x15, 0x08, 0x03, 0x32, 0x39, 0x24, 0x2f,
    0x8d, 0x86, 0x9b, 0x90, 0xa1, 0xaa, 0xb7, 0xbc, 0xd5, 0xde, 0xc3, 0xc8, 0xf9, 0xf2, 0xef, 0xe4,
    0x3d, 0x36, 0x2b, 0x20, 0x11, 0x1a, 0x07, 0x0c, 0x65, 0x6e, 0x73, 0x78, 0x49, 0x42, 0x5f, 0x54,
    0xf7, 0xfc, 0xe1, 0xea, 0xdb, 0xd0, 0xcd, 0xc6, 0xaf, 0xa4, 0xb9, 0xb2, 0x83, 0x88, 0x95, 0x9e,
    0x47, 0x4c, 0x51, 0x5a, 0x6b, 0x60, 0x7d, 0x76, 0x1f, 0x14, 0x09, 0x02, 0x33, 0x38, 0x25, 0x2e,
    0x8c, 0x87, 0x9a, 0x91, 0xa0, 0xab, 0xb6, 0xbd, 0xd4, 0xdf, 0xc2, 0xc9, 0xf8, 0xf3, 0xee, 0xe5,
    0x3c, 0x37, 0x2a, 0x21, 0x10, 0x1b, 0x06, 0x0d, 0x64, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x79, 0x48, 0x43, 0x5e, 0x55,
    0x01, 0x0a, 0x17, 0x1c, 0x2d, 0x26, 0x3b, 0x30, 0x59, 0x52, 0x4f, 0x44, 0x75, 0x7e, 0x63, 0x68,
    0xb1, 0xba, 0xa7, 0xac, 0x9d, 0x96, 0x8b, 0x80, 0xe9, 0xe2, 0xff, 0xf4, 0xc5, 0xce, 0xd3, 0xd8,
    0x7a, 0x71, 0x6c, 0x67, 0x56, 0x5d, 0x40, 0x4b, 0x22, 0x29, 0x34, 0x3f, 0x0e, 0x05, 0x18, 0x13,
    0xca, 0xc1, 0xdc, 0xd7, 0xe6, 0xed, 0xf0, 0xfb, 0x92, 0x99, 0x84, 0x8f, 0xbe, 0xb5, 0xa8, 0xa3
};

private final int[] mul13 = new int[]{
    0x00, 0x0d, 0x1a, 0x17, 0x34, 0x39, 0x2e, 0x23, 0x68, 0x65, 0x72, 0x7f, 0x5c, 0x51, 0x46, 0x4b,
    0xd0, 0xdd, 0xca, 0xc7, 0xe4, 0xe9, 0xfe, 0xf3, 0xb8, 0xb5, 0xa2, 0xaf, 0x8c, 0x81, 0x96, 0x9b,
    0xbb, 0xb6, 0xa1, 0xac, 0x8f, 0x82, 0x95, 0x98, 0xd3, 0xde, 0xc9, 0xc4, 0xe7, 0xea, 0xfd, 0xf0,
    0x6b, 0x66, 0x71, 0x7c, 0x5f, 0x52, 0x45, 0x48, 0x03, 0x0e, 0x19, 0x14, 0x37, 0x3a, 0x2d, 0x20,
    0x6d, 0x60, 0x77, 0x7a, 0x59, 0x54, 0x43, 0x4e, 0x05, 0x08, 0x1f, 0x12, 0x31, 0x3c, 0x2b, 0x26,
    0xbd, 0xb0, 0xa7, 0xaa, 0x89, 0x84, 0x93, 0x9e, 0xd5, 0xd8, 0xcf, 0xc2, 0xe1, 0xec, 0xfb, 0xf6,
    0xd6, 0xdb, 0xcc, 0xc1, 0xe2, 0xef, 0xf8, 0xf5, 0xbe, 0xb3, 0xa4, 0xa9, 0x8a, 0x87, 0x90, 0x9d,
    0x06, 0x0b, 0x1c, 0x11, 0x32, 0x3f, 0x28, 0x25, 0x6e, 0x63, 0x74, 0x79, 0x5a, 0x57, 0x40, 0x4d,
    0xda, 0xd7, 0xc0, 0xcd, 0xee, 0xe3, 0xf4, 0xf9, 0xb2, 0xbf, 0xa8, 0xa5, 0x86, 0x8b, 0x9c, 0x91,
    0x0a, 0x07, 0x10, 0x1d, 0x3e, 0x33, 0x24, 0x29, 0x62, 0x6f, 0x78, 0x75, 0x56, 0x5b, 0x4c, 0x41,
    0x61, 0x6c, 0x7b, 0x76, 0x55, 0x58, 0x4f, 0x42, 0x09, 0x04, 0x13, 0x1e, 0x3d, 0x30, 0x27, 0x2a,
    0xb1, 0xbc, 0xab, 0xa6, 0x85, 0x88, 0x9f, 0x92, 0xd9, 0xd4, 0xc3, 0xce, 0xed, 0xe0, 0xf7, 0xfa,
    0xb7, 0xba, 0xad, 0xa0, 0x83, 0x8e, 0x99, 0x94, 0xdf, 0xd2, 0xc5, 0xc8, 0xeb, 0xe6, 0xf1, 0xfc,
    0x67, 0x6a, 0x7d, 0x70, 0x53, 0x5e, 0x49, 0x44, 0x0f, 0x02, 0x15, 0x18, 0x3b, 0x36, 0x21, 0x2c,
    0x0c, 0x01, 0x16, 0x1b, 0x38, 0x35, 0x22, 0x2f, 0x64, 0x69, 0x7e, 0x73, 0x50, 0x5d, 0x4a, 0x47,
    0xdc, 0xd1, 0xc6, 0xcb, 0xe8, 0xe5, 0xf2, 0xff, 0xb4, 0xb9, 0xae, 0xa3, 0x80, 0x8d, 0x9a, 0x97
};

private final int[] mul14 = new int[]{
    0x00, 0x0e, 0x1c, 0x12, 0x38, 0x36, 0x24, 0x2a, 0x70, 0x7e, 0x6c, 0x62, 0x48, 0x46, 0x54, 0x5a,
    0xe0, 0xee, 0xfc, 0xf2, 0xd8, 0xd6, 0xc4, 0xca, 0x90, 0x9e, 0x8c, 0x82, 0xa8, 0xa6, 0xb4, 0xba,
    0xdb, 0xd5, 0xc7, 0xc9, 0xe3, 0xed, 0xff, 0xf1, 0xab, 0xa5, 0xb7, 0xb9, 0x93, 0x9d, 0x8f, 0x81,
    0x3b, 0x35, 0x27, 0x29, 0x03, 0x0d, 0x1f, 0x11, 0x4b, 0x45, 0x57, 0x59, 0x73, 0x7d, 0x6f, 0x61,
    0xad, 0xa3, 0xb1, 0xbf, 0x95, 0x9b, 0x89, 0x87, 0xdd, 0xd3, 0xc1, 0xcf, 0xe5, 0xeb, 0xf9, 0xf7,
    0x4d, 0x43, 0x51, 0x5f, 0x75, 0x7b, 0x69, 0x67, 0x3d, 0x33, 0x21, 0x2f, 0x05, 0x0b, 0x19, 0x17,
    0x76, 0x78, 0x6a, 0x64, 0x4e, 0x40, 0x52, 0x5c, 0x06, 0x08, 0x1a, 0x14, 0x3e, 0x30, 0x22, 0x2c,
    0x96, 0x98, 0x8a, 0x84, 0xae, 0xa0, 0xb2, 0xbc, 0xe6, 0xe8, 0xfa, 0xf4, 0xde, 0xd0, 0xc2, 0xcc,
    0x41, 0x4f, 0x5d, 0x53, 0x79, 0x77, 0x65, 0x6b, 0x31, 0x3f, 0x2d, 0x23, 0x09, 0x07, 0x15, 0x1b,
    0xa1, 0xaf, 0xbd, 0xb3, 0x99, 0x97, 0x85, 0x8b, 0xd1, 0xdf, 0xcd, 0xc3, 0xe9, 0xe7, 0xf5, 0xfb,
    0x9a, 0x94, 0x86, 0x88, 0xa2, 0xac, 0xbe, 0xb0, 0xea, 0xe4, 0xf6, 0xf8, 0xd2, 0xdc, 0xce, 0xc0,
    0x7a, 0x74, 0x66, 0x68, 0x42, 0x4c, 0x5e, 0x50, 0x0a, 0x04, 0x16, 0x18, 0x32, 0x3c, 0x2e, 0x20,
    0xec, 0xe2, 0xf0, 0xfe, 0xd4, 0xda, 0xc8, 0xc6, 0x9c, 0x92, 0x80, 0x8e, 0xa4, 0xaa, 0xb8, 0xb6,
    0x0c, 0x02, 0x10, 0x1e, 0x34, 0x3a, 0x28, 0x26, 0x7c, 0x72, 0x60, 0x6e, 0x44, 0x4a, 0x58, 0x56,
    0x37, 0x39, 0x2b, 0x25, 0x0f, 0x01, 0x13, 0x1d, 0x47, 0x49, 0x5b, 0x55, 0x7f, 0x71, 0x63, 0x6d,
    0xd7, 0xd9, 0xcb, 0xc5, 0xef, 0xe1, 0xf3, 0xfd, 0xa7, 0xa9, 0xbb, 0xb5, 0x9f, 0x91, 0x83, 0x8d
};


private int[] state;
private int[] expandedKey;

private int[] plaintext;
private int[] cipher;
private int[] decryptedPlaintext;

public void AES_Encrypt(int[] message) {

    message = new int[]{
        0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04,
        0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08,
        0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c,
        0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f, 0x10
    };
    this.plaintext=message;
    int[] state = message;
    int noOfRound = 9;

    //expand the keys
    int[] key = new int[]{
        0x2b, 0x28, 0xab, 0x09,
        0x7e, 0xae, 0xf7, 0xcf,
        0x15, 0xd2, 0x15, 0x4f,
        0x16, 0xa6, 0x88, 0x3c
    };

    expandedKey = new int[176];

    this.expandedKey = keyExpansion(key, expandedKey);

    state = addRoundKey(state, key);

    for (int i = 1;
            i <= noOfRound;
            i++) {
        state = subBytes(state);
        state = shiftRows(state);
        state = mixColumn(state);
        int[] roundKey = new int[16];
        for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
            roundKey[j] = expandedKey[(16 * i) + j];
        }
        state = addRoundKey(state, roundKey);
    }

    state = subBytes(state);

    state = shiftRows(state);
    int[] roundKey = new int[16];
    for (int j = 0;
            j < 16; j++) {
        roundKey[j] = expandedKey[160 + j];
    }

    state = addRoundKey(state, roundKey);
    System.out.println("Encryption Finished!");
    this.cipher=state;
    this.state = state;
}

public void AES_Decrypt(int[] cipher) {
    int[] roundKey = new int[16];
    for (int j = 0;
            j < 16; j++) {
        roundKey[j] = expandedKey[160 + j];
    }
    state=addRoundKey(state, roundKey);
    state=invShiftRows(state);
    state=invSubBytes(state);

    for (int i = 9; i >= 1; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
            roundKey[j] = expandedKey[(16 *i) + j];
        }
        state=addRoundKey(state, roundKey);
        state=invMixColumn(state);
        state=invShiftRows(state);
        state=invSubBytes(state);
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
        roundKey[j] = expandedKey[j];
    }
    state=addRoundKey(state, roundKey);
    decryptedPlaintext=state;
    System.out.println("Decryption Finished!");
    System.out.println("Plain text = Cipher = Plaintext");
    for(int i=0;i<16;i++){
        System.out.println(plaintext[i]+"="+this.cipher[i]+"="+decryptedPlaintext[i]);
    }
}

public int[] keyExpansionCore(int[] in, int round) {
    //rotate
    int temp = in[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < in.length; i++) {
        in[i - 1] = in[i];
    }
    in[in.length - 1] = temp;

    //subbyte
    for (int i = 0; i < in.length; i++) {
        in[i] = sbox[in[i]];
    }

    //rcon
    in[0] ^= rcon[in[0]];

    return in;
}

public int[] keyExpansion(int[] inputKeys, int[] expandedKeys) {
    //first 16 bytes are the original key
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        expandedKeys[i] = inputKeys[i];
    }

    //variables
    int bytesGenerated = 16;//bytes generated so far
    int rconIteration = 1;//rcon iteration begins at 1
    int[] temp = new int[4];//temporary storage for core

    while (bytesGenerated < 176) {
        //read four bytes of the core
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            temp[i] = expandedKeys[i + bytesGenerated - 4];
        }
        //perform expansion core for every newly generated bytes
        if (bytesGenerated % 16 == 0) {
            temp = keyExpansionCore(temp, rconIteration);
            rconIteration++;
        }
        //XOR temp with [bytesGenerated-16] and store in expanded key
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (bytesGenerated >= 176) {
                System.out.println("");
                break;
            }
            expandedKeys[bytesGenerated] = expandedKeys[bytesGenerated - 16] ^ temp[i];
            bytesGenerated++;
        }
    }
    return expandedKeys;
}

private int[] subBytes(int[] state) {
    for (int i = 0; i < state.length; i++) {
        state[i] = sbox[state[i]];
    }
    return state;
}

private int[] invSubBytes(int[] state) {
    for (int i = 0; i < state.length; i++) {
        state[i] = invSBOx[state[i]];
    }
    return state;
}

private int[] shiftRows(int[] state) {
    int[] temp=new int[state.length];

    temp[0]=state[0];
    temp[1]=state[5];
    temp[2]=state[10];
    temp[3]=state[15];

    temp[4]=state[4];
    temp[5]=state[9];
    temp[6]=state[14];
    temp[7]=state[3];

    temp[8]=state[8];
    temp[9]=state[13];
    temp[10]=state[2];
    temp[11]=state[7];

    temp[12]=state[12];
    temp[13]=state[1];
    temp[14]=state[6];
    temp[15]=state[11];

    return temp;

}

private int[] invShiftRows(int[] state) {
    for (int j = 1; j < 4; j++) {
        int time = j;
        while (time > 0) {
            int temp = state[state.length-(4-j)]; ;
            int i ;
            for (i = state.length-(4-j); i >j+4 ; i = i - 4) {

                state[i]=state[i-4] ;
            }
            state[i] = temp;
            time--;
        }
    }

    return state;

}

private int[] addRoundKey(int[] state, int[] key) {
    for (int i = 0; i < state.length; i++) {
        state[i] ^= key[i];
    }
    return state;
}

private int[] mixColumn(int[] state) {
    int[] tmp = new int[16];
    tmp[0] = (mul2[state[0]] ^ mul3[state[1]] ^ state[2] ^ state[3]);
    tmp[1] = (state[0] ^ mul2[state[1]] ^ mul3[state[2]] ^ state[3]);
    tmp[2] = (state[0] ^ state[1] ^ mul2[state[2]] ^ mul3[state[3]]);
    tmp[3] = (mul3[state[0]] ^ state[1] ^ state[2] ^ mul2[state[3]]);

    tmp[4] = (mul2[state[4]] ^ mul3[state[5]] ^ state[6] ^ state[7]);
    tmp[5] = (state[4] ^ mul2[state[5]] ^ mul3[state[6]] ^ state[7]);
    tmp[6] = (state[4] ^ state[5] ^ mul2[state[6]] ^ mul3[state[7]]);
    tmp[7] = (mul3[state[4]] ^ state[5] ^ state[6] ^ mul2[state[7]]);

    tmp[8] = (mul2[state[8]] ^ mul3[state[9]] ^ state[10] ^ state[11]);
    tmp[9] = (state[8] ^ mul2[state[9]] ^ mul3[state[10]] ^ state[11]);
    tmp[10] = (state[8] ^ state[9] ^ mul2[state[10]] ^ mul3[state[11]]);
    tmp[11] = (mul3[state[8]] ^ state[9] ^ state[10] ^ mul2[state[11]]);

    tmp[12] = (mul2[state[12]] ^ mul3[state[13]] ^ state[14] ^ state[15]);
    tmp[13] = (state[12] ^ mul2[state[13]] ^ mul3[state[14]] ^ state[15]);
    tmp[14] = (state[12] ^ state[13] ^ mul2[state[14]] ^ mul3[state[15]]);
    tmp[15] = (mul3[state[12]] ^ state[13] ^ state[14] ^ mul2[state[15]]);

    return tmp;
}

private int[] invMixColumn(int[] state) {
    int[] tmp = new int[16];
    tmp[0] = (mul14[state[0]] ^ mul11[state[1]] ^ mul13[state[2]] ^ mul9[state[3]]);
    tmp[1] = (mul9[state[0]] ^ mul14[state[1]] ^ mul11[state[2]] ^ mul13[state[3]]);
    tmp[2] = (mul13[state[0]] ^ mul9[state[1]] ^ mul14[state[2]] ^ mul11[state[3]]);
    tmp[3] = (mul11[state[0]] ^ mul13[state[1]] ^ mul9[state[2]] ^ mul14[state[3]]);

    tmp[4] = (mul14[state[4]] ^ mul11[state[5]] ^ mul13[state[6]] ^ mul9[state[7]]);
    tmp[5] = (mul9[state[4]] ^ mul14[state[5]] ^ mul11[state[6]] ^ mul13[state[7]]);
    tmp[6] = (mul13[state[4]] ^ mul9[state[5]] ^ mul14[state[6]] ^ mul11[state[7]]);
    tmp[7] = (mul11[state[4]] ^ mul13[state[5]] ^ mul9[state[6]] ^ mul14[state[7]]);

    tmp[8] = (mul14[state[8]] ^ mul11[state[9]] ^ mul13[state[10]] ^ mul9[state[11]]);
    tmp[9] = (mul9[state[8]] ^ mul14[state[9]] ^ mul11[state[10]] ^ mul13[state[11]]);
    tmp[10] = (mul13[state[8]] ^ mul9[state[9]] ^ mul14[state[10]] ^ mul11[state[11]]);
    tmp[11] = (mul11[state[8]] ^ mul13[state[9]] ^ mul9[state[10]] ^ mul14[state[11]]);

    tmp[12] = (mul14[state[12]] ^ mul11[state[13]] ^ mul13[state[14]] ^ mul9[state[15]]);
    tmp[13] = (mul9[state[12]] ^ mul14[state[13]] ^ mul11[state[14]] ^ mul13[state[15]]);
    tmp[14] = (mul13[state[12]] ^ mul9[state[13]] ^ mul14[state[14]] ^ mul11[state[15]]);
    tmp[15] = (mul11[state[12]] ^ mul13[state[13]] ^ mul9[state[14]] ^ mul14[state[15]]);

    return tmp;
}

}
```

Here, In the above code I have set plainText variable hardcodely {1,2,3...} and hadn't done anything with that variable but after when encryption is finished values in that variable is changed to:

```
229 229 194 215 33 194 140 198 156 97 114 26 175 194 23 113
```

What is the reason? I double checked but didn't find any changing condition.
Please! Help me. Because of this I could not further progress my project.

Comment: `plainText` and `state` are both referencing the same array (`message`). Modifying one will modify the other. Perhaps you meant to make a copy? `int[] state = Arrays.copyOf(message, message.length);`

Comment: No, just use [`Arrays.copyOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-int:A-int-)

Comment: For byte arrays you can just use `.clone()` if you need a full copy.

Comment: @4castle
Please can you explain what happens when we use array=array??? just like in my case

Comment: @MaartenBodewes
Please can you explain what happens when we use array=array??? just like in my case